# JavaFX 2.0 Example Crashed On Startup Showing Chinese

Tags: javafx-2

I am running Netbeans 7.1 RC1 with Java 7.0 and each time i try to run my javafx example, it crashes.

Below is the example that I was trying to run:

```
Scene scene = new Scene(new Group());
        stage.setTitle("Imported Fruits");
        stage.setWidth(800);
        stage.setHeight(600);

        ObservableList<PieChart.Data> pieChartData =
                FXCollections.observableArrayList(
                new PieChart.Data("Grapefruit", 13),
                new PieChart.Data("Oranges", 25),
                new PieChart.Data("Plums", 10),
                new PieChart.Data("Pears", 22),
                new PieChart.Data("Apples", 30));
        final PieChart chart = new PieChart(pieChartData);
        //chart.setTitle("Imported Fruits");
         chart.setLegendVisible(false);
        // chart.setLabelsVisible(false);
        //chart.setEffect(new GaussianBlur());

        ((Group) scene.getRoot()).getChildren().add(chart);

        Timeline timeline = new Timeline();

        timeline.getKeyFrames().addAll(
                new KeyFrame(
                Duration.ZERO,
                new KeyValue(chart.rotateProperty(), 0), new KeyValue(chart.translateXProperty(), 0+ chart.getWidth()),new KeyValue(chart.translateXProperty(), 0 + chart.getHeight())),
                new KeyFrame(
                Duration.seconds(5),
                new KeyValue(chart.rotateProperty(), 360), new KeyValue(chart.translateXProperty(), 800 - chart.getWidth()),new KeyValue(chart.translateXProperty(),  600 - chart.getHeight())));
        //timeline.play();
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
```

And while running this code, it crashes and if I run an empty canvas, it will run successfully:

Each time I runt he code above, it crashes like this:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
�
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
�
java.lang.NullPointerException
�
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
�
java.lang.NullPointerException
�
�
⌠䄠晡瑡氠敲牯爠桡猠扥敮⁤整散瑥搠批⁴桥⁊慶愠創湴業攠䕮癩牯湭敮琺
�
⌠⁅塃䕐呉低彁䍃䕓卟噉佌䅔䥏丠⠰硣〰〰〰㔩⁡琠灣㴰砰〰〰㝦敦㘶㡡愷愬⁰楤㴱㘸㈸Ⱐ瑩搽㌰〴
�
⌠䩒䔠癥牳楯渺‷⸰ⵢㄴ�
⌠䩡癡⁖䴺⁊慶愠䡯瑓灯琨呍⤠㘴ⵂ楴⁓敲癥爠噍 ㈱⸰ⵢㄷ⁭楸敤⁭潤攠睩湤潷猭慭搶㐠捯浰牥獳敤⁯潰猩
⌠偲潢汥浡瑩挠晲慭攺
⌠䌠⁛橡癡晸ⵦ潮琮摬氫へ㍡愷慝
�
⌠䙡楬敤⁴漠睲楴攠捯牥⁤畭瀮⁍楮楤畭灳⁡牥⁮潴⁥湡扬敤⁢礠摥晡畬琠潮⁣汩敮琠癥牳楯湳⁯映坩湤潷�
�
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
�
⌠䅮⁥牲潲⁲数潲琠晩汥⁷楴栠浯牥⁩湦潲浡瑩潮⁩猠獡癥搠慳�
⌠䌺屄体呥捨屰硜䍯汯牦畬䍩牣汥獜桳彥牲彰楤ㄶ㠲㠮汯�
�
⌠䥦⁹潵⁷潵汤⁬楫攠瑯⁳畢浩琠愠扵朠牥灯牴Ⱐ灬敡獥⁶楳楴�
⌠†桴瑰㨯⽢畧牥灯牴⹳畮⹣潭⽢畧牥灯牴⽣牡獨⹪獰
⌠周攠捲慳栠桡灰敮敤⁯畴獩摥⁴桥⁊慶愠噩牴畡氠䵡捨楮攠楮⁮慴楶攠捯摥�
⌠卥攠灲潢汥浡瑩挠晲慭攠景爠睨敲攠瑯⁲数潲琠瑨攠扵朮
�
java.lang.NullPointerException
�
    at com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
�
Java Result: 1
```

Comment: Do you have chinese locale installed? What kind of program did you run? Did you checked your machine for viruses? I'm asking last question cause google translate these messages as hardly connected words looks like spam to me.

Comment: The code below always crashes on my system but it runs with just an empty canvas

Answer (score 0):

It seems like one of your programs are modified, the generated code makes no sense at all. it's most certainly a malicious code involved but it's hard to pinpoint the source, might be your configuration files, might be the core of your used software, you sure you're using genuine version of the software? and didn't download/purchase it from un-authorized websites/vendors?

Comment: I downloaded all my binaries from Oracle website and I use a genuine version of Windows 7 running on a high end 64 bit Sony Laptop. Am not sure I understand what you are talking about

Answer (score 0):

It works well now. The problem I guess is because Netbeans JavaFX projects created from Netbeans 7.1beta has issues when you try to run the same project in a newer Netbeans 7.1 such as RC2 which was what happened in my case.